# critical events in hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

I'm using acronis drive monitor to see if my hard drive is getting hotter.
and it seems like there's no problem in temperature but I see critical events:
[image]

The critical events are growing when I turn off my computer during the night and turn it on again in the morning.

I tried using check disk before and it solved event id 137. And I accidentally resolved event id 57 when I improperly turn off the computer.
Tried issuing this command:

```
chkdsk /r /x
```

But it cant solve the problem, what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Through a lot of thread hopping it seems this might do something for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939615